# No Audio in RAM Preview on a 60fps Composition

Tags: after-effects

I encountered a bizarre problem with Adobe After Effects CC 2015: whenever I try to reproduce a RAM preview of my composition, I can't hear audio and this problem occurs only with composition set up with 60 frames per second. If I create a new composition in 30fps or less, After Effects reproduces audio normally. What can I do? (yes, the green bar is fully loaded)

More info: I use a Macbook Pro with OSX 10.10.4, AE 2015.0 and 6GB of RAM are allocated by default to AE

Comment: Welcome hiru :) Sounds like a bug. Might be better to send a bug report instead. Anyway, enjoy video.se! Start with the tour to get your first badge: http://video.stackexchange.com/tour ;)

Comment: it could be a problem with the videos youre trying to loads framerate not mathcing the actual project